# Has Donald Trump ever had a 50,000 domestic arena crowd?

Tags: donald-trump

Eric Trump, in an interview with Fox News Jeanine Pirro, [claimed the following](https://time.com/5838104/eric-trump-coronavirus-disappear/):

> “They think they’re taking away Donald Trump’s greatest tool, which is being able to go into an arena and fill it with 50,000 people every single time…”

Has Donald Trump ever had a domestic arena crowd of 50,000 (as certified by an independent organization)?

Comment: There are three different assertions in your question: Does he draw crowds of 50,000 (this year, presumably), in the title; has he ever drawn a crowd of 50,000 (in your question); and does he draw a crowd of 50,000 every time (from Eric Trump). Can you clarify which claim you want checked?

Comment: I didn't want to repeat he question in the title (and don't think that I stated, or even implied, "this year" anywhere (teh question has been editted- not by me - I intend to roll it back)). It is easy to verify from multiple sources, including trump himself, that he has has drawn crowds of less thank 50k, so that leaves us with "has he ever once, at any time, drawn a domestic crowd of 50k". Feel free to edit again for clarity.

Comment: Thanks -- the now-edited phrase in the title I was looking at was something like "does he draw..." which implies recency, presumably pre-COVID-19. I suspect the answer will be "yes, he has drawn 50,000" to an arena, with a "but he doesn't do it regularly."

Comment: I would be happy to accept such a answer. I have been unable to find evidence of it myself, but that doesn't mean that it didn't happen.

Comment: I'll note that there is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rallies_for_the_2016_Donald_Trump_presidential_campaign) listing Trump's rallies for the 2016 election season.  The largest crowd listed is, I believe, 28,000-30,000.  The documentation on the page is sparse, however, and crowd numbers for post-election rallies are not given.

Comment: I have seen that. The sister page, [List of post-election Donald Trump rallies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_post-election_Donald_Trump_rallies) does not give crowd sizes.

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect that there would even be any independent organization that would "certify" stuff like this?

Comment: One possible line would be to look down the Wikipedia post-election rally list and see which of the venues actually have capacity for 50,000.  Those, if any, could then be investigated further.  Most of the rallies listed were at indoor sports arenas which typically have capacities that are significantly smaller.

Comment: I looked at those listed for 2019 and 2020.  None of those venues have capacity over about 22,000, so I think that would make the claim false if taken literally.  On the other hand, some events could have additional "overflow" attendees who don't go inside the venue but watch the proceeding on a video screen outside the venue or at some other nearby location.  Not sure if this is enough for an answer.

Comment: There was a rally on Dec 17, 2016, at Ladd-Peebles Stadium in Mobile, AL, which apparently has a capacity of 50,000 for concerts (though only 33,000 for football games).  But [USA Today reported](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2015/08/21/donald-trump-alabama-rally/32140669/) a crowd of "about 30,000" for that event.

Comment: On the other hand, there's [this story](https://www.coloradopolitics.com/quick-hits/trump-campaign-says-more-than-70-000-signed-up-for-tickets-to-colorado-springs-rally/article_88a3fb14-54d8-11ea-bd9c-3b1f81d9f8a2.html) saying that (per the Trump campaign) more than 70,000 people "signed up" for tickets to a rally in Colorado, at which there were 10,000 people inside the arena and a similar number estimated outside.  It's not clear what happened to the other 50,000 ticket holders so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I wonder if they were charging for those tickets ;-)

Comment: So, I think in order to answer this, we need a more precise definition of "crowd".

Comment: In a spirit of generosity, let's say, those who attended, whether in or outside - after all, their intention was to get inside and see him - ***But***, obviously, only independently verified or esteemed numbers.

Comment: @NateEldredge `I looked at those listed for 2019 and 2020 ... Not sure if this is enough for an answer` it's the closest that we are going to get for an answer - post it, and I will accept it